# Ordering an alias column in union query

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query that utilises a union a few times, and within it I've created an alias column called 'Category'. When I try a simple order by on the alias column it works fine. However the data in my alias column has numbers and they order like 1,10,11 instead of 1,2,3 etc..

When I try changing my order by to order by len, I suddenly get 2 errors... 1 advising that columnn 'Category' doesn't exist and the other stating 'ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if the statement contains a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator'. The same applies when I try casting it as an INT

A slimmed down version of the query is as follows...

```
SELECT 'Category 1' as Category, category1Score as categoryScore
from table1
WHERE lineNumber = 'Reflow 2' and dateOfAudit between '01/10/2019' and 
'10/10/2019'
UNION
SELECT 'Category 2' as Category, category2Score as categoryScore
from table1
WHERE lineNumber = 'Reflow 2' and dateOfAudit between '01/10/2019' and 
'10/10/2019'
UNION
SELECT 'Category 10' as Category, category10Score as categoryScore
from table1
WHERE lineNumber = 'Reflow 2' and dateOfAudit between '01/10/2019' and 
'10/10/2019'
```

I want it to order by Category 1, Category 2, Category 10 for example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ORDER BY with UNION and ALIASES with complex query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46188075/using-order-by-with-union-and-aliases-with-complex-query)

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
select Category,  categoryScore from
(
SELECT 'Category 1' as Category, category1Score as categoryScore,1 as ord
from table1
WHERE lineNumber = 'Reflow 2' and dateOfAudit between '01/10/2019' and 
'10/10/2019'
UNION
SELECT 'Category 2' as Category, category2Score as categoryScore,2
from table1
WHERE lineNumber = 'Reflow 2' and dateOfAudit between '01/10/2019' and 
'10/10/2019'
UNION
SELECT 'Category 10' as Category, category10Score as categoryScore,3
from table1
WHERE lineNumber = 'Reflow 2' and dateOfAudit between '01/10/2019' and 
'10/10/2019'
)A order by ord
```

Answer (score 0):

Subquery and then order by the `Category` column:

```
SELECT Category, CategoryScore
FROM
(
    SELECT 'Category 1' AS Category, category1Score AS categoryScore, 1 AS pos
    FROM table1
    WHERE lineNumber = 'Reflow 2' AND dateOfAudit BETWEEN '01/10/2019' AND '10/10/2019'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Category 2', Category2Score, 2
    FROM table1
    WHERE lineNumber = 'Reflow 2' AND dateOfAudit BETWEEN '01/10/2019' AND '10/10/2019'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Category 10', category10Score, 3
    FROM table1
    WHERE lineNumber = 'Reflow 2' AND dateOfAudit BETWEEN '01/10/2019' AND '10/10/2019'
) t
ORDER BY
    pos;
```

Notes:

I use `UNION ALL` here instead of `UNION`, because your intention is most likely to not remove duplicates.  Also note that you only need to use aliases in the first query of the union.  In fact, subsequent aliases would just be ignored.

Finally, I chose to introduce a new computed column called `pos`, which encodes the order you want for each query in the union.  While we *could* rely on only the `Category`, sorting on category could behave unexpectedly later on if your query might change, as it is text, and not a pure number.

Answer (score 0):

Try For below Query..

```
 with CTE as 
(
    SELECT 'Category 1' as Category, category1Score as categoryScore
    from table1
    WHERE lineNumber = 'Reflow 2' and dateOfAudit between '01/10/2019' 
and '10/10/2019'
    UNION
    SELECT 'Category 2' as Category, category2Score as categoryScore
    from table1
    WHERE lineNumber = 'Reflow 2' and dateOfAudit between '01/10/2019' 
    and '10/10/2019'
    UNION
    SELECT 'Category 10' as Category, category10Score as categoryScore
    from table1
    WHERE lineNumber = 'Reflow 2' and dateOfAudit between '01/10/2019' 
    and '10/10/2019'
) select Category,categoryScore from CTE
ORDER BY
    Category ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `union` for the outer query?

```
select c.Category,
       (case ord
            when 1 then category1Score
            when 2 then category2Score
            when 3 then category3Score
            when 4 then category4Score
            when 5 then category5Score
            when 6 then category6Score
            when 7 then category7Score
            when 8 then category8Score
            when 9 then category9Score
            when 10 then category10Score
            when 1 then category1Score
        end) as categoryScore
from table1 t1 cross join
     (select 'Category 1' as category, 1 as ord union all
      select 'Category 2', 2 as ord union all
      select 'Category 3', 3 as ord union all
      select 'Category 4', 4 as ord union all
      select 'Category 5', 5 as ord union all
      select 'Category 6', 6 as ord union all
      select 'Category 7', 7 as ord union all
      select 'Category 8', 8 as ord union all
      select 'Category 9', 9 as ord union all
      select 'Category 10', 10 as ord
     ) c
where t.lineNumber = 'Reflow 2' and
      t.dateOfAudit between '2019-10-01' and '2019-10-10'
order by c.ord;
```

This reduces the scope of error when you write the query, by having the filtering conditions on your table in only one place.